# Swift date format with millisecond component

Tags: ios, swift4

All,

I have a date format `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"` and I need to set the millisecond value, but date component does not provide millisecond attribute.

Below is my code for setting custom values in hour, minute, second. I also need to set millisecond to `0/999` value.

```
static func getToadyStartInUTC() -> String{
    let todaydate = Date()
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    
    var components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour], from: todaydate)
    components.hour = 0
    components.minute = 0
    components.second = 0

    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let startDate = calendar.date(from: components)!
    
    print("\(startDate)")
    
    formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC")
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"
   return formatter.string(from: startDate)
}
```

How can I set the millisecond value in date component?

Comment: Are you passing the timestamp in milliseconds? If yes, what's your input and output?

Comment: @Bharat Right now my func return "2021-01-18T05:00:00.000Z" this date . I need to set millisecond to 999 .

Comment: @Bharat I need "2021-01-18T05:00:00.999Z"

Comment: Did you try components.nanosecond = milliseconds * 1000000 ?

Comment: @PtitXav Thanks. I'll try that

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution with `Calendar` API to get `startDate` and `ISO8601DateFormatter`

```
static func getToadyStartInUTC() -> String {
    let todaydate = Date()
    var calendar = Calendar.current
    let timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)!
    calendar.timeZone = timeZone

    let startDate = calendar.startOfDay(for: todaydate)
    var components = calendar.dateComponents(in: timeZone, from: startDate)
    components.nanosecond = 999000000

    let formatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
    formatter.formatOptions.insert(.withFractionalSeconds)
    return formatter.string(from: components.date!)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let todaydate = Date()
    var calendar = Calendar.current
     
    calendar.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC")


    let startDate = calendar.startOfDay(for: todaydate)
    var components = calendar.dateComponents(in: timeZone, from: startDate)
    components.nanosecond = 999000000

    let formatter = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"

   
     formatter.string(from: components.date!)
```